# Applescript: replace a ( with ASCII in curl

Tags: curl, sed, awk, applescript

I am trying to use curl with a domain name with a "(" in it, by using curl from applescript, but this does not work

I have been bumbling around trying to use awk and sed, but failing.

Can anyone help me please to replace the "(" with the correct code.

Comment: HOW are you using curl, provide an example please.

Comment: A domain name with a parenthesis in it would require punycode conversion before you pass it to curl. Did you do that?

Comment: Hi no I am a noob I am afraid and did not do punycode... do you have any examples. here is how I am using curl from within an applescript do shell script set tmdbURL to "http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.search/en/xml/key/Fargo (1996)"
 
 -- get xml
 set theOutputFile to DL_stringposix
 set theCommand to "curl " & tmdbURL & " -o " & theOutputFile
 do shell script theCommand

Comment: This is a poor question. Please include your *actual* code and *actual* error message when asking a question of this nature.

Answer (score 0):

The domain name in your example doesn't include parentheses. The URL does.

You can replace the parentheses using `sed` like this:

```
sed -e 's/(/%28/g' -e 's/)/%29/g'
```

You may also need to replace the space: `sed 's/ /%20/g'`.

However, `curl` should be able to handle parentheses in the URL just fine. You say it "does not work" [which conveys no information at all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice). You should post exactly what you're doing, exactly how the result differs from your expectations and exactly what error messages you're getting.

Guessing that you may be getting an error such as "-bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('", that can be fixed using proper quoting:

```
curl "api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.search/en/xml/key/Fargo (1996)"
```

However, when I try it, I get an "400 Bad Request" message from the host. When I do the substitutions above in various combinations (including trying an underscore for the space), I get no response at all (but that's probably because I don't have an API key). In any case, it doesn't appear to be the parentheses that are problematic, but the space.

Anyway, looking at their [documentation](http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/methods/Movie.search), they give an example of how to include a date:

```
http://api.themoviedb.org/2.1/Movie.search/en/xml/APIKEY/Transformers+2007
```